# Check if some edge crosses some minimal cut

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

I am struggling with the following question (and solution actually):

> Given $G(V,E)$, a flow-network (capacities are integers), We denote the maximum-flow value by $f^*$. Check for an edge $e$ if:
>    1. It crosses some minimal-cut.
>    2. It crosses every minimal-cut.

The solution suggests:

1. Decrease the capacity of the edge $e$ by $1$ and check if the new maximum flow equals $f^*-1$. return true if so.
2. Increase the capacity of the edge $e$ by $1$ and return true iff the max-flow increased.

I'd be glad if you could explain to me what's the idea behind this algorithm.

Thanks

Comment: What to you mean by $f^*-1$? Is $f^*$ the value of the flow here or the flow vector?

Comment: $f^*$ is the value (integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use the max flow-min cut theorem on several levels.

For 1., suppose $e$ is in some minimal cut $C$. Then $f^*=u(C)$ where $u$ is the capacity vector. Now, if we decrease the capacity of $e$ by 1, we get $\tilde{u}(C)=u(C)-1=f^*-1$, where $\tilde{u}$ is the new capacity vector. But $C$ is still a minimal cut with respect to $\tilde{u}$ (do you see why?), so by the max flow-min cut theorem the new optimal flow is $f^*-1$ and the algorithm returns true.

On the other hand, if the algorithm returns true, then by a similar argument you get that since the new optimal flow is $f^*-1$, the minimal cut value has decreased by 1. And that can only happen if $e$ is in some minimal cut.

The second question is (very) similar, I let you try it.

Comment: $C$ is still a minimal-cut because we just made it a "better minimal cut".

Comment: Yep that is it.